# How to get rid of quotes in start and end of column values of spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, single-quotes

I exported dataframe into csv format. Some of its columns datatype changed from vector to string. The column values changed from **[0.350562388776,0.203056015074,-0.313145598397]** to **'[0.350562388776,0.203056015074,-0.313145598397]'**

I tried to convert it as a vector for which i used -

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
list_to_vector_udf = udf(lambda l: Vectors.dense(l), VectorUDT())
vectors = df.select(
list_to_vector_udf(df["result1"]).alias("res1"),
list_to_vector_udf(df["result2"]).alias("res2")
)
```

The column's datatype has changed from string to vector but as i applied vectorassembler it is giving an error **ValueError: could not convert string to float: [0.389866781754-0.180391363533-0.212950805169]**. 
I searched for its solutions, got the solutions for this errors but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally is not a good approach, nevertheless try to just eval the result (result is kind of trusted, right?)

```
>>> a = eval('[1,2,3'])
>>> print(a)
[1,2,3]
```

Be aware though, that you are probably using this lib in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks! I applied it on a column of pandas dataframe and it is working fine but do you have any idea that how to apply it on a column of spark dataframe.

Comment: Could you please give an example. Thanks.